# Thrift on Spark on Mesos using DC/OS

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere, apache-spark-sql

I've installed Zeppelin from the DC/OS universe.
My question is, and I've been unable to find any answer for this - How do I Install Thrift on Mesos in order to use SparkSQL?

What are the steps I need to perform?

Thanks